# Android resumes my Activity even if i call FINISH on BackButton

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity A that launches B with an Intent. (B is a `MapActivity` and has some async code)

in B i have the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
//          Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");

     finish();
     return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This simply not work. I mean that when I press the back button on the phone, the current activity B disappears and the activity A that launched B is shown.

If I press again on A the button that launch B, I see B is exactly how it was when I closed it. SAME text in textboxes, same Map position... So i think the activity B is not really closed.

How can I close it for real so when I launch again it, activity B is cleas as new born?

EDIT: just to make the question clearer:
I want it to work like this: when the user is on activity B and BACK button is pressed, B has to be closed and destroyed. When the user again launches B from A, B has to be launched as a NEW activity, with blank field, reset map, etc., etc., ... just like the first time the user launches B from A.

Comment: please show onCreate/onPostCreate/onResume for activity B and how you launch it from A

Comment: So you dont want the back button to do anything in this activity? Or what>

Comment: @coder-for-life22 : added EDIT in the question to have the question clearer.

Comment: @tabbykitten i don't have onPostCreate/onResume for activity B.
i have only onCreate and  some basic standard code like:
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home1);
other code simply manage layout controls...

Comment: the finish(); could have killed the activity, another question is did u store your text/data in some static variable which still persist thru out? 
another way is in your manifest, you can specifically do a no history to activity B. check if the data is still there. if they are still there, there's a high chance you are storing your data in some static/global variable.

Comment: OMG! you completely right! i checked for this problem in past days but i couldn't find it as... i've not UPDATED from SVN. my coworker inserted lines of code that prefill fields by some static var!

Thanks guy. but now i don't know what answer accept. 
@Jianhong if you post it as a reply i would mark it as ACCEPTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i stated in my last comment to the post, @Jianhong given me the correct answer (aslso if as a comment). As he don't copied the comment as answer in time, i add this answer and mark it as the ACCEPTED. Thanks @Jianhong!

Answer:
@Jianhong OMG! you completely right! i checked for this problem in past days but i couldn't find it as... i've not UPDATED from SVN. my coworker inserted lines of code that prefill fields by some static var!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning true, try returning super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) after finish().
You can try 1 more thing: specify android:noHistory="true" in the manifest for that activity.
Specifying this attribute doesn't keep the activity on the Activity Stack.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried lauching B by calling startActivityForResult() in A?

Do all your processing in B and then ensure you call finish on it and this should clear all data in it.

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious. OnSaveState is called when finishing activity, and this activity is popped out of the stack. Best practice for you to clear the situation is to log all the lifecycle events in both activities, it will help to figure out where to put initializing your B activity.

Yes, and one more thing try researching onNewIntent method in B activity i suppose it will be really helpfull